# cannot checkin from SSMS could not load file or assembly microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.controladapter

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have the following installed on my machine:

SQL Server 2012 developer edition
VS Express 2013 for Web
VS Express 2013 For Desktop
TFS Express 2013

I can check in/out my projects through both VS Express 2013 installs, I am wanting to make my Stored Procs encrypted so need to keep unencrypted copies within a solution in TFS so have this setup but whenever I try to check in via SSMS I get the error:

Could not load file or assembly
"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.ControlAdapter"
Version=12.0.0.0

Has anyone experienced this before or have a solution how to resolve it as the file does exist on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the latest MSSCCI Provider found on visual studio gallery? And have you checked the SSMS options under source control provider, that it is set to Team Foundation Server. Remember that MSSCCI Provider requires Team Explorer 2013 to be installed as well.